# How to print the type of error from Pandas merge?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to print the error from a pandas merge when common columns exist?

```
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'outer')
```

I have this inside a loop and I'm wanting the script to continue through the loop when it finds a common column error. I could use,

```
    try:
        df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'outer')
    except:
```

However, if possible, I'd like to see the type of error

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54462606/edit) with full traceback to include the "common column error" you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the classic:

```
try:
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'outer')
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Although it's bad form to catch overly general errors, so it would be better to see what kind of errors you might get (`ValueError`, `KeyError`, etc) and put them all in a list.

```
try:
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, 'outer')
except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
    print(e)
```